# Android HighCharts Library returns Error:Failed to resolve: com.highsoft.highcharts:6.0.2:

Tags: android, highcharts, android-highcharts

A few days ago I saw **HighCharts Library** is available for Android for graph.

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android

I read the documentation and start it to add on my project but when I am trying to add gradle to my project I'm getting error:

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.highsoft.highcharts:6.0.2:
> Open File

[image]

There are two ways as they mentioned in their documentation:

> A) You can download the aar from here: Highcharts and add it manually. Put the aar in the libs folder in your project structure.
>
> B) You can add the library to the gradle dependecies from JCenter.

When I added .aar file to libs folder there is no issue but when I added below code:

```
HIGChartView chartView = (HIGChartView) findViewById(R.id.hc);
```

My project not able to find out class `HIGChartView`. I'm not able to find out whether it's my side issue or HighCharts Library issue.

I also downloaded poject by Github, Getting no issue on their Project also compare Gradle with their project but I'm not able to find out the issue.

My **build.gradle(Module:App) :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kabloom.highcharts2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.highsoft.highcharts:6.0.2' // HighCharts here added

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating issue on github they replied and solved my issue...

**Their Documentation having problem** :

[image]

**Incorrect Class :**

```
HIGChartView chartView = (HIGChartView) findViewById(R.id.hc);
```

**Correct Class :**

```
HIChartView chartView = (HIChartView) findViewById(R.id.hc);
```

And Please note that the library need Gson to work so add it in your dependencies like this:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

Also , They replied :

> Unfortunatelly Highcharts Android is not avilable from jcenter yet so
>   you need to add library manually. You can do that by following direct
>   instructions from A) point from readme.

**Reference Working Code :**

**build.gradle(Module:App):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package_name.highchartdemo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile (name: 'highcharts-release', ext:'aar')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

**MainActivity :**

```
   package com.package_name.highchartdemo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.highsoft.highcharts.Core.*;
import com.highsoft.highcharts.Common.HIChartsClasses.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        HIChartView chartView = (HIChartView) findViewById(R.id.hc);

        HIOptions options = new HIOptions();

        HIChart chart = new HIChart();
        chart.type = "column";
        options.chart = chart;

        HITitle title = new HITitle();
        title.text = "Demo chart";

        options.title = title;

        HIColumn series = new HIColumn();
        series.data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4));
        options.series = new ArrayList<HISeries>(Collections.singletonList(series));

        chartView.options = options;
    }
}
```

**activity_main:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.highsoft.highcharts.Core.HIChartView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/hc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.package_name.highchartdemo.MainActivity"/>
```

Comment: I am facing an issue at `<com.highsoft.highcharts.core.HIChartView` please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67446196/6854117)?

Comment: Hi Abhishek kumar I am still facing issue regarding HighChart can you help me with this

Comment: Please check the latest version code from the official website.